# Reverse data function

Tags: functions

I applied the function below to my numeric data (each piece of numeric data in a database) and then realised I had not backed it up.  The function is

```
function(x) {
return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}
```

Once I'd stopped swearing I tried to reverse the applied function without success, probably because my maths is not up to it.  Is the function reversible and if so, how.  I'd love to learn how this can be done.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data? is Min and Max over a static set of data or is it changing? Do you know those values before you applied the change?

Comment: The data is just a line of integers and real numbers and is static and  I do (did) know the values before the change.

Comment: OK, if this is the case, the original values may be re-obtained. Could you provide 5 values of the old and new data points to check my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the minimal and maximal are not known, then unfortunately you can't get back the original data. For example both the data $(-1,0,1)$ and  $(-2,0,2)$ will be map to $(0,0.5, 1)$.

However, if you have kept the minimal $m$ and the maximal value, $M$, then it is possible to reverse the process. Try to think if it's possible to recover two input output pairs for your data set.

$$y = \frac{x-m}{M-m}$$

then $$x=y(M-m)+m$$

would give you back the original data.

Comment: Assuming $x$ is the original value and $y=(x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))$ the value of x is $$x=y(max-min)+min$$ However, I am not sure that this will restore the original value, it could but can we assume it must restore the original value?

Comment: Given the min and max, this is just a linear map (which is a bijection) isn't it?

Comment: True, however, your first sentence in the answer is a strong "No" :)

Comment: I see, that is a sentence under the setting that minimum and maximum is not known, now that it is known, it can be recovered. In fact, two input and output pairs are suffices.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification/